# Add a subproject by CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, apache-arrow

[Apache Arrow](https://github.com/apache/arrow) submodule is stored at `thirdparty/apache_arrow/cpp`, so my main CMakeLists.txt looks like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(arrow_parcer VERSION 0.1.0)

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(thirdparty/apache_arrow/cpp)
```

At the `thirdparty/apache_arrow` stored whole [Apache Arrow](https://github.com/apache/arrow) project.

When I'm trying to build project, last output lines is follow:

```
[cmake] CMake Error: INSTALL(EXPORT) given unknown export "arrow_targets"
[cmake] Generating done
[cms-driver] Error during CMake configure: [cmake-server] Failed to compute build system.
```

Apache Arrow can be easily builded by CMakeLists.txt at `/cpp` folder, but why there is an error if I trying to include it by `add_subdirectory`?

Comment: where does that "arrow_targets" come from?

Comment: Yes, this is part of the question. There is no matches for `"arrow_targets"` in whole `apache_arrow` folder. Not a single one.

Comment: Not every project is intended to be built via `add_subdirectory` approach. Have you tried to build ApacheArrow project as **standalone**, giving its `cpp/` subdirectory as source directory to `cmake`?

Comment: Yes, I tried and I was able to build it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache Arrow C++ is not meant to be built using `add_subdirectory`, instead you should use CMake's [`ExternalProject_Add` facility](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) to build it:

```
ExternalProject_Add(arrow_ep 
    URL "https://www.apache.org/dist/arrow/arrow-0.15.1/apache-arrow-0.15.1.tar.gz"
    SOURCE_SUBDIR cpp)
```

Instead of using `URL` you can also use different providers like `GIT_REPOSITORY`, too.

Comment: Is there a way to determine if a given CMake project is intended/able to be consumed by `add_subdirectory()` or if it needs the full `ExternalProject_Add()` treatment?

Comment: I'm trying to use Apache Arrow Data Types in my C++ project and as I've seen in your C++ implementation documentation on your official website, I need to include the header <arrow/api.h>. Although I added Apache Arrow to my project the same way you mentioned in your answer, I'm still receiving the error arrow/api.h not found. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You will need to also need to add an `include_directories` directive that points to the directory where the built artifacts are. See how we do this for snappy in Arrow: https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/cpp/cmake_modules/ThirdpartyToolchain.cmake#L701-L717 Similar lines are needed in addition to `ExternalProject_Add`.

Comment: @genpfault I think the "way" to determine is: 1. if this project is really important to your main project; 2. if you have enough time and patience to read the external project's CMake and whole build system. You can use `add_subdirectory` to consume any project if you allow there are some hacks and workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't really need to setup the installation, here is a hack-y way to do this. In the `CMakeLists.txt` adding arrow's source dir, you define your own `install`.

```
function(install)
endfunction()
add_subdirectory(${arrow_SOURCE_DIR}/cpp ${arrow_BINARY_DIR})
```